# How can I put my rearview mirror back on?

Tags: mirrors

I pulled my rearview mirror off when I was doing a tint (and I didn't do the tint well so I'll re-do it), but how can I put it back on?

That screw doesn't look like it can be unscrewed, but I haven't tried. Even if I can unscrew it, how would I screw it back in after?

**UPDATE:**

I tried sliding the panel down, but it won't move.

I added 2 more photos, I noticed that there are 2 metal hooks inside (one on each side). Could they be part of a mechanism? Maybe the hole in the bottom middle is a key hole. I tried using a paperclip, but I couldn't get anything to move.

**UPDATE 2:**

I found this Removal Service Point in the car manual, but I don't understand what I'm supposed to do. Is the "slit" the thing that looks like a keyhole? And what is the spring?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the lowest picture, the "silver" part looks like it is designed to slide down and out of the black part.

So, slide it out and refit it with the screw. Then you can slide it back into place on the holder, which was the way to remove it in the first place.

Comment: good idea, I'll try that

Comment: I attached a diagram from the manual, but I don't understand it.

Comment: So use a small screwdriver to move the latch or spring then the part comes out... until you release that catch it will not slide out.